# MySql delete multiple records by comma separated list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure in mysql to delete multiple records from a table by providing list of id as a comma separated list.

example

(*please note that Id column in the table is integer*)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `deleteLines`(IN $ids varchar(1000))
BEGIN
    select * from line where  $ids in ($ids);
END$$
DELIMITER;

CALL deleteLines('1,3,5,12');
```

What is the best way to delete multiple records in this scenario?

Comment: Creation of a sproc is a specific part of the brief?

Comment: Why do you need a procedure for such a simple task? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615566/delete-where-id-in-list

Comment: This stored procedure will call by an application. Rather than calling inline SQL statement from application, I have moved it to a stored procedure. Later if needs a modification it will be easy to do anything without compiling the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do this, use `find_in_set()`:

```
select * from line where find_in_set(id, in_ids);
```

Actually, the definition should look more like this if you want to *delete* the records:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteLines`(
    IN in_ids varchar(1000)
)
BEGIN
    delete from line
    where find_in_set(id, in_ids);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Thank you, This is what exactly I wanted.